# Android Google Maps Services causes building error

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, google-maps-android-api-2, proguard

I want to use Google Maps Geocoding API in my Android project. So I add the `google-maps-services` as described [in official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library) by the line:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
    ...
}
```

and have such error:

`Unable to compute hash of .../release/classes.jar`

How can I fix it? Maybe add some proguard rules?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Yes, I think something with your proguard, on empty projects I got everything correct. Anyway, maybe Geocoder will help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Google Geocoding library. Source code says that it contains the following dependencies: `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0' compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'`. I've already use all three libraries in my project. Don't you know how can I configure proguard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to implement this on an empty project, and it worked fine.

I saw other people reported they fix a similar issue by removing `minifyEnabled true` line. Maybe you should try that too.

Just in case, this is my gradle files:

`//Module:app`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.kylelam.geocoding"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
}
```

//Project: Geocoding

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And also my onCreate function:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Replace the API key below with a valid API key.
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("AIzaSyCZ5QqX69Hbsx7UG2eX5rMzLLd4aiYNdJ8");
    GeocodingResult[] results = new GeocodingResult[0];
    try {
        results = GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
                "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway").await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(results[0].formattedAddress);

    TextView helloworld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloworld);
    helloworld.setText(results[0].formattedAddress);
```